# Check for carriage return at the end of a file

Tags: c, string

I have a text file. I have to check to ensure that the file is ending with a Carriage return. If it is not ending with one then I would like to insert one. The file now being of the correct format I can use it for further parsing. It should work in both Windows & Linux environments.

Comment: There's lots of "text files". You need to know the encoding: plain ascii, utf-8, ebcdic (oh! wait -- Windows & Linux don't use this), jis, ..., ...

Comment: @Tony : i could not figure out a way to check for the EOF & check for Carriage Return simultaneously . How do i do that ?

Comment: i will reach the EOF . once i do that can i go two steps back and say something like if(ch==0x0D) printf("ok") else fp_write.put("0x0D") . meaning if i find a Carriage return then its ok i will not take any action but in case i dont , then i would keep a write stream pointer and write the Carriage return to it . Then i can rename the file subsequently .

Comment: Most people are too lazy or busy, and won't return the carriages.  That is why the rental kiosks at the airport provide a $0.25-$0.50 incentive for homeless people to round up and return the carriages.

Comment: LOL@ Paul. @rockstar: smells like a state-machine. You'll need 2+1 states, or some more if you want to handle CR,CR+LF,LF,LF+CR correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
FILE *file = fopen(path, "r+");
char c;
fseek(file, -1, SEEK_END);
fread(&c, 1, 1, file);
if (c != '\r') { /* This will work on Win/Linux and also on a Mac */
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  fprintf(path, "\r");
}
fclose(file);
```

Note: Are you sure you mean 0x0D? In Linux, lines are ended by 0x0A (\n) and in Windows by the combination 0x0D 0x0A (\r\n).

Comment: `\n` isn't a carriage-return, although perhaps the questioner has asked for the wrong thing. The questioner's comments back up that it really is ASCII CR (`0x0D`) that's wanted, though, so `\r`.

Comment: I suspect OP asked for the wrong thing and does not know what "carriage return" means...

Comment: Why would a text file in Windows/Linux end with a carriage return? It just doesn't make sense, so I assumed he meant the end-of-line character(s). But ok, I'll change the answer.

Comment: I agree, I don't think the reason I commented warrants a downvote even before your edit. I just thought it was confusing to use `\n` without mentioning that it's a different character, since the questioner has looked up the value of an ASCII CR so certainly that's the character he's interested in for the moment. Could be this further parsing is very lax about linebreaks, and so `\r` at the end satisfies it (and if the file was already linebreak-terminated, it sees a blank line).

Comment: @klas : fread syntax is incorrect . nevertheless ur idea is good & i have used it in my program .

Comment: @rockstar Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @rockstar If this solution worked for you please accept it so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

see i have prepare one file

```
    FILE *b = fopen("jigar.txt","w");
    fprintf(b,"jigar\r");
    fclose(b);
```

now i have again open that file for checking

```
 b = fopen("jigar.txt","r");
 char f;
```

go to end of file to last

```
while(fscanf (b, "%c", &f) != EOF);
```

go 1 byte previous

```
  fseek( b,-1,1);
```

read that byte

```
    fscanf(b,"%c",&f);
```

check it

```
    if(f == 13)  \\ here instead of 13 you can writr '\r'
        printf("\r is detected");
    else
          write \r to file...
```

Comment: It is probably more efficient to use read/write mode to access the file and fseek to get to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

    FILE *file = fopen("me.txt", "r+"); // A simple text file created using vim 

    char buffer[100] ;

    fseek(file, -2, SEEK_END); // Fetches the last 2 characters of the file 

    fread(buffer,1,2,file); // Read the last 2 characters into a buffer 

    printf("\n Character is %s",buffer); // Will print the entire contents of the buffer . So if the line ends with a "\n" we can expect a new line to be printed 

    //Since i am interested to know how the line feeds & Carriage returns are added to the end of the file , i try to print then both . I have run this code under Suse Linux and if i press enter key after the last line in the file i get two "\n" in the output . I confirmed this using GDB . I would like to run in a Windows environment and check how the behavior changes if any .
    printf(" --is %c",buffer[1]);
    printf(" --is %c",buffer[2]);

    if(buffer[1]=='\r' || buffer[2]=='\n')
    //take action 
    else 
    // take another action


    fclose(file);
}
```